# Delete uploaded file if not saved

Tags: java, jsf-2, image-upload

I have implemented a file upload using tomahawk on JSF 2. User must upload and crop an image. When user uploads an image, before showing it, the image is saved in file system. If after uploading an image, user moved to another link I want to delete the uploaded file. Is there a way to know if some action is not performed?

Comment: Are the upload and crop two separate processes, i.e. can you track them both individually with some kind of boolean state variable (`isCropped` and `isUploaded`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is a table in database, where you have stored information about uploaded file and its path.

Make a scheduled process on the server, that runs on regular basis and checks the table with information about uploaded files along with other database information.

And delete orphan file records with files from the filesystem.

Comment: yes there is, but that is my last choice, anyway thanks for response

Comment: As far as I understand your task there is no other 100% working approach. For instance, you can intercept events when user leaves page where image has been uploaded. But what if user opened another browser window and continues work with another objects? Your server side application won't know about such situations. And your server will store unecessary files/db records.

Comment: Scheduling seems to be the answer.